# Wrong shows time filter kibana 3 (utc)

Tags: tomcat, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-3

When entering the time in the time filter, Kibana (3.1.2) does not account for my time zone (utc+4). What's the matter... tomcat, elastic or kibana?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time picker at the top right shows the dates in your local time, however, the `range` filter uses the equivalent UTC dates in order to filter your documents.

What you see in the filter is the exact UTC dates used to filter your documents.

`2016-07-26T00:13:18.740Z` (at UTC+0) in the filter is equivalent to (i.e. the same date as) `Jul 26, 2016 04:13:18` (at UTC+4) in the time picker.

So there are no errors here, simply a visual disconnect between the date you've selected and the date you're seeing in the `range` filter.

Comment: Do you need more info on this?

Comment: How to make a filter shows the same time as the top?

Comment: As far as I know, Kibana 3 doesn't support this, that was only "fixed" in Kibana 4, if memory serves.